# include ITK headers and link libraries in a makefile

Tags: makefile, cmake, itk

I understand the typical way to include ITK to your own project is using findITK macro in Cmake. But now I have a makefile that is from another project. How can I incorporate ITK using makefile efficiently? A minimal example will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no *efficient* way to incorporate ITK into non-CMake managed project. But there is a way: create a [hello world](https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/HelloInsight) application which uses ITK+CMake, configure CMake to create project files for your make system of choice (e.g. Visual Studio, or make), and then copy definitions (include paths, list of libraries etc) from those project files to your original project files (`makefile`s).

Comment: Yes, this is currently what I am doing. If there is no other efficient way, I will probably do this in the future.